# How can I get a list of dates between two given dates with mysql?

Tags: mysql

I need to generate a list of dates with MySQL between two given dates. This list of dates must be filtered to the dates that correspond to Tuesday and Thursday. Is it possible?

Comment: Did my answer ever work for you ???

Comment: Did my answer ever work for you ???

Answer (score 2):

A really easy way to do it is to have a table of numbers. Query this table for numbers less than the number of days between the two dates, and select the smaller date plus the number to return the dates themselves. Easy to stick a predicate in the where clause to handle Tuesdays and Thursdays too.